# How to implement logic using elasticsearch Pagination using ElasticsearchRepository in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Is there any way to use ElasticsearchRepository which extends from PagingAndSortingRepository. This allows built-in support for pagination and sorting.
But I am not able to change my implementation to use ElasticsearchRepository. I just want to know how to apply:

1. How to use Post Search
2. How to use esQuery which basically providing Search query
   String esQuery = String.format(searchTextQuery, startDate, endDate, formattedQueries);
3. How to use that Post URI which I m getting as below:
   Request request = new Request("GET", "/" + user.getUserId() + "/_search");
   So with all the above, how to use Pagination with ElasticsearchRepository
   Below is my service code:

   ```
   public List getResponses(ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate, 
   String cat, FieldFilterVM filter, String query) throws IOException {
   User user = (User) 
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
   Request request = new Request("GET", "/" + user.getUserId() + "/_search");
   List<String> matchQueries = new ArrayList<>();
   matchQueries.addAll(formatCategoryQuery(cat));
   matchQueries.addAll(formatFilterQuery(filter, false));
   if (query != null && query.length() > 0) {
       matchQueries.add(String.format(textFilterQuery, query));
   }
   StringBuilder formattedQueries = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < matchQueries.size(); i++) {
       formattedQueries.append(',');
       formattedQueries.append(matchQueries.get(i));
   }
   String esQuery = String.format(searchTextQuery, startDate, endDate, 
   formattedQueries);
   request.setJsonEntity(esQuery);
   Response response = 
   elasticSearchService.getClient().getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
   String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), 
   "UTF-8");
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Map map = mapper.readValue(responseBody, new TypeReference<Map>() {
   });
   List matchedTextResponses = new ArrayList();
   if (map != null) {
       List<Map> textResponses = (List<Map>) ((Map) 
   map.get("hits")).get("hits");
       for (Map textResponse : textResponses) {

       }
   }
   return matchedTextResponses;
   }
   ```

Comment: IÄd suggest you read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference on how to use Spring Data Elasticsearch. It seems you try to implement the communicaiton to Elasticsearch all by yourself?

Comment: How to use search_after with rest low client API::
String esQuery = String.format(searchTextQuery, startDate, endDate, formattedQueries);
  request.setJsonEntity(esQuery);
  String offset = String.valueOf((Integer.parseInt(from)*Integer.parseInt(size)));
  request.addParameter("size",size);
  request.addParameter("from",offset);
  Response response = elasticSearchService.getClient().getLowLevelClient().performRequest(request);
  String responseBody = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");